# Inline Editing of Component Link's fields in 2013 SP1

Tags: experience-manager

I have a component(outer component) with Component Link(Inner component) field. I want to make fields of inner component inline editable. I tried the put tcdl tags to do the same as mentioned in few of the posts and got the page output as shown in attached image. Output tags seem to be correctly formed still I am not able to see the fields of inner component on my page (2nd attached image). Am I missing something in my code?[image]

[image]

DWT code :

```
        tcdl:ComponentField name="address"
             a tridion:href="@@Field@@">city${TemplateRepeatIndex} /a
        tcdl:ComponentField
   </h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code it looks like you're just rendering the inner component as a component link, I.e. a hyperlink to a component (see chapter in docs re Dynamic Componet Linking).  You need to actually render the inner component's fields.

So add your inner component's   markup, and render the fields of the inner Component Presentation along with the XPM field markup.

Answer (score 1):

As per Nickoli, you are rendering the inner component as a component link, not as an editable (visible) set of fields. Therefore, you only see the title you enter within the link tag `city${TemplateRepeatIndex}` and not the contents of the linked component.

In order to make the fields within the inner component visable, and therefore editable, you will need to render markup (complete with XPM markup) to the page for each field within the inner component.

You can do this in two ways:

1. Add the markup code in the current component template, accessing the linked component directly, or via TBB added values.
2. As a seperate component template using the `@@RenderComponentPresentation(InnerComponentField, "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE_ID")@@` markup.

Comment: Thanks Chris, can you provide me some example code if possible?

Comment: Finally I am able to do it.